# Stumped on the role of a particular statement in a program with Arrays & Nested For Loops

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm teaching myself **C** with KN King's book

I have been going through examples providing by the author, and adding my own notes in Visual Studio.

I get the "big picture" of the loops contained within the program below, but some of the details are lost on me.

I was hoping you could enlighten me on the role of the statement that is circled in red below in the pictures? What is it doing?

Picture 1 - full program:

[image]

Picture 2 - with bottom two loops chopped off, displays expected result fine:

[image]

Within the context of that first loop's brackets, the statement in red seems unnecessary. But when I delete it, I get a program that doesn't function as intended. So it must be tied to one of the two loops below it. I'm scratching my head what it actually does.

The author alludes to the purpose in BOLD-FACED TEXT below but he isn't 100% explicit what is going on. It's strange because the statement in red deals with an array containing the Initial Balance, but in the loop it is contained in deals with the interest rate labels on the top row of the print.

The author says says:

> The second row is a little trickier, since its values depend on the numbers in the first row. Our solution is to store the first row in an array as it's computed, then use the values in the array to compute the second row.

Any help would be much appreciated!

I included the text from the book and the source code below

> **Computing Interest**
>
> Our program prints a table showing the value of $100 invested at different rates of interest over a period of years. The user will enter an interest rate and the number of years the money will be invested. The table will show the value of the money at one-year intervals---at that interest rate and the next four higher rates---assuming that interest is compounded once a year. Here's what a session with the program looks like:
>
> Enter interest rate: 6 Enter number of years: 5
>
> Clearly, we can use a For Statement to print the first row.
>
> The second row is a little trickier, since its values depend on the numbers in the first row. Our solution is to store the first row in an array as it's computed, then use the values in the array to compute the second row.
>
> Of course, this process can be repeated for the third and later rows.
>
> We will end up with two For Statements, one nested inside the other: -The outer loop will count from 1 to the number of years requested by the user -The inner loop will increment the interest rate from its lowest value to its highest value
>
> Note the use of NUM_RATES to control two of the For Loops. If we later change the size of the array called value, the loops will adjust automatically.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_RATES (sizeof(value)/sizeof(value[0]))     /*   NUM_RATES is a macro that finds the length of the array 
                                                   based on the SIZE OF THE     ARRAY in bytes ( size of(value) ) DIVIDED BY the SIZE OF EACH ELEMENT ( sizeof(value[0])  )   */
#define INITIAL_BALANCE 100.00



main()
{
int low_rate;                         /*User input --- the lowest interest rate*/
int num_years;                        /*User input --- the number of years*/
int i; 
int year;
float value[5];                       /*Remember that the number in the brackets represents the number of elements --- 1 for each of the 5 year timeline in this case */

printf("Enter interest rate: ");
scanf_s("%d", &low_rate);
printf("Enter number of years: ");
scanf_s("%d", &num_years);


printf("\nYears");                 /*This statement prints out the label for the "YEAR" column on the left side of the chart */



/*This loop prints out the LABELS FOR THE INTEREST RATE ROW AT THE TOP.  Right next to the "Year" */

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_RATES; i++) {    /*   NUM_RATES is 5 here
                                         Remember that NUM_RATES, seen above, is a macro for (sizeof(value)/sizeof(value[0]))
                                         This macro measures the LENGTH of the array by dividing the array size in bytes by the element size in bytes
                                         The macro format makes it easy for the loops to adjust if we need to CHANGE THE SIZE OF THE ARRAY   */
    
    printf("%6d", low_rate + i);         /* Prints out the low rate + i   according to the loop above */
                                            
    
    value[i] = INITIAL_BALANCE;
}



printf("\n");                       /*   This statement starts a new line for the loop below   */



/*   This loop prints the numbers IN THE YEARS COLUMN.    Counts from 1 to the number of years entered by the user   */

    for (year = 1; year <= num_years; year++) {
        printf("%3d    ", year);



        /*   This NESTED loop increments the interest rate FROM ITS LOWEST VALUE TO ITS HIGHEST VALUE AND MULTIPLIES IT BY $100. Occurs right after the year column entry printed   */
        for (i = 0 ;  i < NUM_RATES ; i++) {
            value[i] = value[i] + ( ((low_rate + i) / 100.0)  *  value[i]);
            printf("%7.2f", value[i]);
        }
            printf("\n");             /*This statement causes the value to be placed on the next line*/
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-) your question is off-topic here. Please look at [ask]

Comment: I don't think it's at all off topic, Jim. Can you explain why you think this?  It's a C question and a specific one.

Comment: in line 39, the fields (float) of array `value` are initialized. `value` is used in the nested loop (line 57).

Comment: It's doing exactly what it appears to be doing: Assigning a value to the elements of `value`.

Answer (score 1):

The line in question:

```
value[i] = INITIAL_BALANCE;
```

will set the value for each element in the array of values to the constant value (i.e. *100.00*). Otherwise, the values in the uninitialized array may be 0 or a random/*garbage* value, depending on the compiler.

See [this sample](http://rextester.com/PODC17749) with updated output. Notice the added keyword *int* before the function declaration for *main()*, as well as the formal arguments *argc* and *argc*. KN King's C book should explain those, though you can find many resources online, such as [The GNU C Programming Tutorial](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html).

Comment: Just a note. The two standard prototypes for `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (of course the variable names `argc` and `argv` can be anything you like, and `argv` is also properly written in the equivalent `char *argv[]` form)  The other archaic designations such as `void main()` are compiler dependent. Your form of `main()` is, by virtue of default types, `int main()` which is fine, minus the explicit `void` but may be quite confusing to new C programmers. Don't use `printf("\n");` to do `putchar('\n');`, no need for the variadic `printf` for one char.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback. I didn't update the function signature initially because I just took the sample from the OP but I have updated the sample and added an explanation for it. Good point about using putchar() - the updated sample utilizes it.